# Flutter - Android Studio - won't recognize the url_launcher import properly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, url, dart

I'm trying to make my app open weblinks and/or installed apps that the user have on his/her phone.

Running `flutter --version` will get:

```
Flutter 1.17.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5f21edf8b6 (6 days ago) • 2020-05-28 12:44:12 -0700
Engine • revision b851c71829
Tools • Dart 2.8.3
```

Im using:

```
    environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I import this in my code:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

I get the following error:

```
Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'url_launcher' in 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart'.
lib/main.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart'
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
       ^
```

if I use the function I got from Google tutorial:

```
  Future<void> _launchUniversalLinkIos(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      final bool nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        universalLinksOnly: true,
      );
      if (!nativeAppLaunchSucceeded) {
        await launch(url);
      }
    }
  }
```

I get the above error plus a few of this errors under it:

```
lib/main.dart:40:15: Error: The method 'canLaunch' isn't defined for the class '_MyStatefulWidgetState'.
 - '_MyStatefulWidgetState' is from 'package:fluttertodolist/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'canLaunch'.
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
              ^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:41:51: Error: The method 'launch' isn't defined for the class '_MyStatefulWidgetState'.
 - '_MyStatefulWidgetState' is from 'package:fluttertodolist/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'launch'.
      final bool nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launch(
                                                  ^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:47:15: Error: The method 'launch' isn't defined for the class '_MyStatefulWidgetState'.
 - '_MyStatefulWidgetState' is from 'package:fluttertodolist/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'launch'.
        await launch(url);
              ^^^^^^
```

I've search for hours and all I found in sStackoverflow questions are not helping, and in also in the tutorials and everywhere else.
everyone suggesting to use the way I already use.

Comment: can you put your flutter version and dart version?

Comment: added after the first sentence @Siloé Bezerra Bispo

Comment: can you update the version of the plugin? to 5.4.10

Comment: I just did, same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for it was one of the 2 things I did:

1) there was an update for android studio + flutter plugin

2) I removed the plugin from the `pubspec.yaml` and from the `pubspec.lock` then I compiled again and then I added them again to the `pubspec.yaml` and compiles

after this 2 it worked, not sure which one b/c they were together.